# Entra ID Cloud Sync fails to writeback password with certificate chain trust error 33010

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-entra-id

I am trying to configure password writeback with Entra Cloud Sync and after configuring everything, including writeback and sspr I am receiving error

```
ErrorEventId
33010
ErrorMessage
A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority.
OnPremisesAgent
CloudSync
```

in password reset audit log from Entra ID portal.

I previously had Entra Connect setup configured on the same server which was allowing me to do both password change and password reset, which ensures me no network, trust or local access issue should be blocking. After disabling Entra Connect, removing the agent from the server and installing Entra Cloud Sync the writeback throws the error.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNydY.png)
I cannot see anything relevant in the event viewer nor logs on the server and suspect something on Entra ID side is erroring out.

How to resolve this issue to get both password change and password reset in the cloud work?